# How to replace text before specific character (regexp)

Tags: javascript, regex

How to replace text before specific character?

I need to replace a text before '{' character.

```
([a-z]+)\s?\{

Text: text {
Replaced by: test
Result: test
```

How to get a result like test {?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `'test{' + 'text{dsdsads'.split('{')[1];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this: `/[\w\s]+(?={)/`

Then you could replace the "text" before the `{` by doing something like:

```
"test2{test1".replace(/[\w\s]+(?={)/,'demo');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a negated `[^ ]` match combined with a *Positive Lookahead*.

```
'text {'.replace(/[^{]+(?={)/, 'test '); //=> "test {"
```